# Read preprocessor macro in Xcode build script?

Tags: xcode, macos, unix, build

Is it possible to read a preprocessor macro from a build script in Xcode?

In my precompiled header I've defined a macro like:

```
#define APIKEY 123abc
```

In my build script I would like to get access to this macro as a variable so that I can do something with it, e.g.:

```
echo $APIKEY > outputfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you will need to search the header file it's `define`d in, in order to find it.  You could use numerous utilities to do that, but `grep` and `awk` are probably the most straight forward and will work in most trivial cases (you might need more if the constant is a string constant):

```
#!/bin/sh

APIKEY=$(grep 'define.*APIKEY' file.h | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: How could I do this but with the preprocessor macros like DEBUG that are defined for the whole project?

Comment: @jamone If you are running in a *build script* (as per the OPs requirements) then they will appear as pre-defined environment variables (i.e. `$SOME_VARIABLE`).  If you require any more help, then please start a new SO question.

Answer (score 12):

There is a more robust way to do this.

When executing a *Run Script* build phase, Xcode lists all the pre-processor definitions that were made by your **Project Build Settings**, inside one environment variable called `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`.

For definitions that you need to access from your script, define them in **Project Build Settings**.  If you are moving these out of your source code, but need to maintain robustness of your source (e.g. you also compile this source outside of the Xcode project) you can optionally retain the source definitions, wrapped with `#ifndef` / `#endif` - thereby making them passive defaults.

Now, to retrieve these as script variables, simply evaluate the content of `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` in your *Run Script* build phase, like this:

```
eval "${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS}"
```

If you want to make sure there is a default value in the script, for one or more specific variables, define them above this evaluation.

Comment: Using Xcode 6 and iOS 8 this works but the environment variable appears to have changed name to `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`. So this becomes:`eval "${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS}"`